# Python Error EOL while scanning string literal from sample script

Tags: python, function, opendaylight

I'm doing some network programming code learning using sample script and running into an error when execute the script. 
This is the function related

```
def calculateCost(data,rate):
        cost = 0
        if rate=='tx':
                transmitted = int(data["node-connector"][0]["opendaylight-port-statistics:flow-capable-node-connector-statistics"]["packets"]["transm$
                cost  = transmitted
        elif rate=='rx':
                received  = int(data["node-connector"][0]["opendaylight-port-statistics:flow-capable-node-connector-statistics"]["packets"]["received$
                cost  = received
        return cost
```

return error below

```
 File "main.py", line 26
    transmitted = int(data["node-connector"][0]["opendaylight-port-statistics:flow-capable-node-connector-statistics"]["packets"]["transm$
                                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I noticed the line missing some bracket and quotn mark...but not sure if that is the problem... perhaps you guyz can help and advise me to correct it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your statements end in the middle of an expression with `$`. It looks like you may have copied the code from a terminal window that truncates lines instead of wrapping them.

Comment: Ohh...no wonder...the end line...seems not complete... I got it from an example file...no idea the actual how it looks like..Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In python, a string in double quotes (`"`) cannot span more than one line. To do that you need to use triple quotes like:
    """foo
    bar""".
In your case, at the end of the line beginning with `transmitting` it looks like the code got cut off where the `$` sign is, so it is missing the closing `"`. This is true on the seventh line as well.

Comment: Ok...thanks for the advise...I will try to change it and see how it will run...